# Necessary to download Win 10 Pro Installer in order to have OS reinstall media?

Tags: windows-10

After using MS's MediaCreationTool to upgrade from Win 7 Home to Win 10 Home on my PC, I upgraded that to Win 10 Pro. This was done completely online and the whole process did not take very long and appeared to have succeeded.

The issue now is I have no way of reinstalling the current version of the OS AFAIK. So my question is, to get this can I just use the MediaCreationTool again only this time download the Win 10 Pro version of the installer?

I'd like to avoid doing that again, if possible, because it'll probably take 12-16 hours to download via my relatively slow DSL Internet connection (as it did when I did went from Win 7 Home → Win 10 Home).

**Solution**

I ended up contacting Microsoft about this and according to them I did need to download the Win 10 Pro installer again and when it asked for a product key enter the product key on the sticker on the back of my PC. I really didn't want to do that because the product on the sticker was actually for Vista Home Premium, but when I upgraded to Win 10 Home the system was running Win 7 Home due to a previous (paid for) upgrade.

So, what I ended up doing was use the MediaCreationTool to download the Win 10 Pro x64 Installer `.iso` file  — it only took about 6 hours to do this time — burned that on to a DVD, and then used it to do a clean install into the same partition that had been upgraded from Vista Home Premium → Win 7 Home → Win 10 Home → Win 10 Pro. However I **did not** enter the product key from the sticker on the PC and instead just picked "Skip" or "Enter later" each time it asked for one.

Afterwards, when I checked the System status, it said it was activated, the installer or the Microsoft license server must have recognized the machine. Things might have been different if I had tried the install on a new hard disk, but I am unable test that scenario at this time.

Comment: Yes you can use the same media. You cannot upgrade to pro for free. Once you upgrade to W10 and activate it, W10 registers your PC with microsoft.  Now you can reinstall W10 clean and it will activate, when you install W10 again skip entering a key, when it finishes installing and gets on the internet it should activate automatically.

Comment: @Moab: I know it's not free — I paid M$ for it. My question arises because when I upgraded from Win 7 to 10, it seems like I had to choose between downloading Win 10 Home or Pro, which led me to think there are must be different installers for each.

Comment: Windows 10 upgrade is Free, why did you pay for it?

Comment: @Moab: I upgraded from Win 7 Home to Win 10 Home for free, but had to pay for upgrading from Win 10 Home to Win 10 Pro as far as I could tell.

Comment: Ah, I would make the media again, this time select Pro. This will save time if you ever have to reinstall for some reason.

Comment: "The issue now is I have no way of reinstalling the current version of the OS AFAIK" - Windows has a **Reset** feature which installs a fresh image of Windows 10.  **Yes** The Media Creation Tool can simply download the Windows 10 .ISO

Comment: @Ramhound: "Reset" sounds promising (assuming I can still boot the computer). Where does it get the fresh image from? If it's via a download I might as well do it now ahead of time, don't you think?

Comment: Built into Windows.  It's well documented

Comment: @Moab: I ended up basically taking the advice in your last comment after Microsoft confirmed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to.

You can reinstall your OS if you can still start windows.

Go to `Start` -> `Settings` -> `Recovery` -> `Reset my windows` and you can go to a fresh install with or without keeping your files.

Comment: I considered that option, but want something that would work even if the installed OS won't boot. Also, although I have software to make a backup image of the C drive, I also want a way to do a clean install.

Comment: It does work if the system cannot boot via WinRE

Answer (score -1):

For new installations you can :

1. Convert the install.esd file to ISO/WIM format and use it to install ( Using software like : NTLite / WinReducer etc. )

   - *Install.esd* is the file used by Windows Update for the upgrade installation, ESD stands for Electronic Software Download and it is an encrypted and compressed WIM file (Windows Imaging Format) that was adopted by Microsoft in newer Windows versions, the main difference is it can not be directly mount or burn or used for install, you have to convert it first.
   - *Install.esd* can be found in : c:\Windows.~BT\Sources\Install.esd (it is hidden) by default or in : C:\RecoveryImage\Install.esd ( If not found, try locating it in other folders if there are any like \ESD\, you can use windows search )
2. Quick and dirty approach - Create image via some imaging software and use this baseline image for further re-installs. ( DriveImage XML etc... )

...

Comment: I know I can make a backup image of my C drive — in fact I've already done it — but would also like the ability to do a clean install of the (Pro) version of the OS.

Comment: Check c:\Windows.~BT\Sources\Install.esd - that should be your Windows 10 install from Windows Update. Use ESDtoISO or NTLite to convert the ESD file to ISO. Install as usual.  If you can not find it there try in  C:\RecoveryImage\Install.ESD.

Comment: Your answer is weak at best, but your comment provides some additional useful information, so please add that to your answer.